# immer JS delete child or nested data

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using immer js and i want to delete the child of my data.

here is my data example

```
data = {
  1: {
    bookName: 'name',
    author: {
      5: {
        authorName: 'John'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and my reducer code

```
return produce(state, draftState => {
  delete draftState.data[bookIndex].author[authorIndex]
  return draftState
})
```

and nothing happen.

Thanks for the help

UPDATE:
when i added a return, the data of that index are removed but the index is still in there.
e.g.

```
data = {
  1: {
    bookName: 'name',
    author: {
      5: 0
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **delete draftState.data [bookIndex].author[authorIndex]**   the space in data[bookIndex] is typo mistake? or you have the space in between there?

Comment: typo in here. sorry